# odoo 12. Attach files

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I need advice.

I want to upload pdf files in the format: Product -> Attribute Name -> Attribute Value. By default, the file is attached only to the current object (product.template).
All this happens in the product.template module. How can i do this?
Now the file is attached only to the product name. 
When the user changes the attribute and the value (field) the file must change. (if it was downloaded)

class LoadPdfAttribute(models.Model):

```
_inherit = ['product.template']

total = fields.Float(string="Total price")
attachment_ids = fields.Many2many('ir.attachment', 'attachment_id', string='Attachments')
product_attribute_value_id = fields.Many2one(
    'product.attribute.value', string='Attribute Value',
    required=True, ondelete='cascade', index=True)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <data>
         <record id="view_form_product_expand_pdf" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">load_pdf_attribute_product_product_template_only_form_view</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//page[@name='purchase']" position="after">
                    <page name="attach_files" string="Attribute files">
                        <group>
                            <field name="total" string="Total"/>
                            <field string="Attribute Value" name="product_attribute_value_id"/>
                            <label for="attachment_ids"/>
                                <div>
                                    <field name="attachment_ids"  widget="many2many_binary" string="Attach a file" class="oe_inline"/>
                                </div>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
            </field>

        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsnAy.png)

Comment: what is the relation between attach file and 'product.attribute.value' ?